# folder system owner is getting changed in case of checkout of var/cache and var/session folder

Tags: magento2, file-permissions, folder

I have set **mage: mage** user for my project it's working fine but whenever I am doing checkout then every time folder owner is getting changed to **root: root** for only var/cache/ & var/session/ folder.

Due to this every time I am getting file permission error on the frontend.

anyone can tell me how to keep the same folder owner when the file is regeneration in the system.

I know, during checkout some new files are generating in var/session folder and permission getting changed for the new file so it's happening.

I am using following command to change folder owner

```
chown -R mage:mage var/
```

but every time when does any file generate owner is getting change to **root:root**
Thanks for the support in advance.

Comment: Did you use recursive permission command? Please share command as well

Comment: for var directory, try www-data user, since most of the time, accessing from browser leads to www-data user. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/`

Comment: I doon't have any user of this name. can I assign root user to var/ folder

Comment: mostly it's a default user, try this command with `www-data`, if it is not working then you can revert it back to `root` or `mage`

Comment: but every time owner is getting changed to root. what should I do now?

Comment: the command is for recursive rights using `-R`, I hope this would be one time command

Comment: friend, my concern is whenever any new file is generating in var/cache or var/session then it owner is getting changed. can you help me about this.

Comment: Have you tried the command that I have shared? I can't help you if you not even try my solution in first place. Try this command `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/` and if you still face new file permissions issue then you can get back to me